# Открыть окно при клике на пункт в админ-баре WP

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

При клике на пункт "Настроить" в админ-баре открывается окно с настройками.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно реализовать аналогичное окно (в будущем со своими настройками) при клике на свой созданный пункт, например "SEO настройки".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите свой код и что у вас конкретно не получается.

Comment: через экшн admin_bar_menu добавьте новый пунк в админ бар, через экш wp_footer выводите свой темплейт для настроек когда вам нужно и после этого напишите js который будет отображать, скрывать и сохранять данные настроек

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/